# How to correctly handle error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm trying to run my code I get error 91, I know the error pops-up because the ar is out of range, but I still want to ignore it. I tried On Error Resume next, but error still pops-up.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim rng As Range, ar As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo errHandler
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("test") _
        .Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
errHandler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

For Each ar In rng.Areas   '<---------- Error 91 on this line

ar.Value = Application.Trim(ar)

Next ar

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `For Each ar In rng`.

Comment: Sorry still same error.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but maybe what you need is the `.Cells` collection instead of the `.Areas` one? Also avoid using `ActiveSheet` and try using explicit references to the worksheet like `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to guard against `rng` being Nothing.  I would set it up like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim ar As Range
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("test").Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   On Error GoTo 0
   
   If Not rng Is Nothing Then
      For Each ar In rng.Areas
         ar.Value = Application.Trim(ar)
      Next ar
   End If
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("test").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` is the accurate range that doesn't need `.Offset(1)` nor includes the first row below the table.